# Uninstalling couchdb built from source

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, couchdb

Can anyone tell me how I uninstall a CouchDB installation built from source using [build-couchdb](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb)? I deleted the build directory as they said, but I can still start and stop it and everything.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I had installed couchdb from the package manager before. Make sure you've removed couchdb and couchdb-bin.